# Cannot read property 'column' of undefined in data tables and cellEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using `DataTables` plugin and [cellEditor](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/blob/master/js/dataTables.cellEdit.js#L105) for the inline editor, I can edit my cell but when I destroy the table and I make another table and I want to edit a cell. I have this error :

> Cannot read property 'column' of undefined in the line [105](https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/blob/9a2b395b4d648ee3fb697a9714cf88780a5283b5/js/dataTables.cellEdit.js#L105).

JS cellEditor :

```
table.MakeCellsEditable({
    "onUpdate" : myCallbackFunction,
    "inputCss" : "my-input-class",
    "columns" : [2],
    "confirmationButton": {
        "confirmCss": 'my-confirm-class',
        "cancelCss": 'my-cancel-class'
    },
    "inputTypes" : [{
        "column" : 2,
        "type" : "number",
        "option" : null,
    }],
});
```

JS datatables :

```
table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "createdRow" : function ( row, data_use, dataIndex ) {
        $(row).attr('id', 'line-' + dataIndex);
    },
    "columnDefs" : [{
        "targets": "_all",
        "createdCell" : function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            $(td).attr('id', 'cell-' + col);
        },
    data : data_use,
    columns : column_name,
    dom : 'frtip',
    responsive : true,
    destroy : true,
    searching: true,
});
```

Comment: Can you share some code of how you're using the plugin

Comment: Please share your code. In your debug window there should be a call stack somewhere. Look at the call stack carefully until you see a line that references code you actually wrote. Share that line and the surrounding lines with us please.

Comment: @Ryan click on the '105' to see the where is the line refered with the error

Comment: that error usually happens when trying to access a property of an object that is null. So line 105 in the cellEditor is var currentColumnIndex = table.cell(this).index().column; try putting a breakpoint there and seeing what the values for table, table.cell(this) and table.cell(this).index() are. one of them is probably null.